# RT not summing for group

Tags: crystal-reports

I have to suppress duplicate details and have created a manual running total including the suppression formulas by group.  The issue is I have three receivings with the same item, same date, same location but different receiving numbers (not duplicates); which do appear on the report.  I must use previous and next functions to have a correct running total of the detail where the duplicates are suppressed but where there is three groups (same item) the center group shows a RT of $0.  I have tried "or" instead of "and" but then the groups with duplication show incorrect running totals.  I have tried previous only but that also present incorrect running totals.  Any suggestions?
Example

```
Grp Receiving# Date   Item# Running Total
1   222        Nov 21 789   $200
2   333        Nov 21 789   $  0
3   444        Nov 21 789   $200
```

Comment: can you post how is your data before running total?

Comment: It happens that these groups only have one detail record and have no duplicates. But here is a example of detail.

Comment: Receiving 1 item 789 $200, Receiving 2 item 789 $200, Receiving 3 Item 789 $200, Receiving 4 item 500 $100 Receiving 4 item 500 $100 (duplicate), Receiving 5 item 600 $50